# How to use HttpSend activity in 2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to call a .Net (asmx) web service that takes a UTC date and returns the local date.

An input to the web service could look like this: `2015-04-30T23:00:00Z`
The output from this call will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">5/1/2015 12:00:00 AM</string>
```

I'm new to web services; I want to use the `HttpSend` activity in my 2013 workflow but apart from `Uri`, which is obvious, **I'm not sure what to put into each of the fields?**

[image]

The web service code:

```
namespace spLeaveBooking.WebServices
{
    public class GetLocalTime : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetLocalTimePlease(string inputDateTime)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(inputDateTime);
            return dateTime.ToLocalTime().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try following configuration for **HttpSend** activity:

1. **RequestHeader** -  Accept:"text/html; charset=utf-8", Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8".
2. **Uri**: URL to access the webservice method.Pass the parameter in querystring. eg:
   `string.Format(".../GetLocalTime.asmx/GetLocalTimePlease/{0}",dateTimeVariable)`

Or

```
string.Format(".../GetLocalTime.asmx/GetLocalTimePlease?inputDateTime={0}",dateTimeVariable)
```

3. **ResponseContent** : Specify the workflow variable which will store the data returned from webservice.

Now after the HttpSend action, you will have to parse the webservice response, stored in the workflow variable. For this use `GetDynamicValueProperty<T>` activity.

Edit: Let's say the webservice returns object of below class:

```
class ReturnData { public string returnDate{ get; set; } }
```

Then your Workflow variable, will be an object of class `ReturnData` , then you will need to to do below configuration to parse it:

**PropertyName**:"returnDate",
**Source**: Name of the workflow variable which has the webservice response content

**Other reference links**:

1. See this solution to know about [parsing the dynamic values](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DynamicValue-Path-c84f9ade#content).
2. See this code solution  for  [HttpSend Activity calling  WCF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Workflow-e14e0e7a#content)

Comment: Unnie, passing of the parameter in the query string is what I'm confused about at the moment. So as mentioned in my question, the parameter that is passed is a `string` that looks like `2015-04-30T23:00:00Z`. You have suggested to use `string.Format`, but I don't see any array parameters e.g. `{0}`? If I wanted to send a hard coded parameter, would the query string look like this: `string.Format(".../GetLocalTime.asmx/GetLocalTimePlease/2015-04-30T23:00:00Z")`?

Comment: Thanks for finding it. i missed the {0} during typing. Yes the hardcoded parameter passed is correct, but you can remove the string.format in that case

Comment: Should this URL with the hard coded parameter also work in the browser? Because it does not. I see a SharePoint error that simply says "Sorry, something went wrong". The URL to ".../GetLocalTime.asmx" works though - I see the web service page where I can select the "GetLocalTime" operation. Also, what would the URL look like if I needed to send two (or more) parameters to the web service? Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I now have this error message in my workflow with the hard coded parameter: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'text/html', Received ContentType : 'text/html'. Content (truncated) : ''. ResponseStatusCode : 'OK' Request Uri : 'http://siteurl/GetLocalTime.asmx/GetLocalTimePlease/2015-04-30T23:00:00Z'

Comment: I think you will have to change the RequestHeader property to text/html instead of text/xml.

Comment: Now I get this error: Exception details: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'text/html', Received ContentType : 'text/html'. Content (truncated) : ''. ResponseStatusCode : 'OK' Request Uri : 'http://siteurl/GetLocalTime.asmx/GetLocalTimePlease/2015-04-30T23:00:00Z'. I can try setting the response to be json by adding this line to the web service code: `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`. But then how do I send the parameter? Can I send it in the query string as with text/html

Comment: Yes you can try with Json, then change your RequestHeader  to Accept "application/json; odata=verbose",Content-Type "application/json; odata=verbose"

Comment: I did that. But how do I send the parameter?

Comment: Try this: string.Format(".../GetLocalTime.asmx/GetLocalTimePlease?inputDateTime={0}",dateTimeVariable)

Comment: OK, progress! No more error now, but I seem to have nothing in the response. I am using a `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity. But what should go in the `Path` field? Looking at my web service code, I am simply returning a string, with no variable name.

Comment: You can try returning a proper json object with a property name and value. For eg: class ReturnData { public string returnDate{ get; set; } }. Return an object of this class. Parse this json and get value in the GetDynamicValueProperties  activity.

Comment: Using your example, would I put "ReturnData" or "returnDate" into the `Path` field of the `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity?

Comment: Use GetDynamicValueProperty<T>  activity. Also edited the answer

Comment: So I've added a class to my project, `ReturnData`. But I'm unable to select the `ReturnData` type when using `GetDynamicValueProperty<T>`. It will not show under any of the available types that are selectable. Or can I select the `Object` type and use this in some way? I feel like we're close to resolving this, so thank you for your input and patience.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the options available

Answer (score 3):

Put a dynamic value variable in the response content box and put this in the RequestHeader box:

[image]

Then after the HttpSend activity add a GetDynamicValue activity in which you extract the values you need:

[image]

Comment: A few questions for you: 1. Do I use the CreateDynamicValue activity first? 2. In this activity do I assign just any random string to the PropertyName property? Or does it need to be the same variable name as defined in the input parameters to the web service? 3. With the GetDynamicValue activity, should the Source property be set to the HttpSend activity's ResponseContent property? 4. In the GetDynamicValue activity, what should go in the Path column? The web service just returns a string. I have updated my question with the web service code.

Comment: Any help with my questions @tomvanderhoek?

Comment: Will look into when i am at home :)

Comment: could really use your help, I can't get HttpSend to work :(

Comment: (1) No, I simply create a DynamicValue variable in the list of variables. (2) Which PropertyName property? (3) Yes definately (4) The response is JSON format, in your path should be one of the column from the response. If you want to view your resonse text try the same HttpRequest in POSTMAN in Chrome :).

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work :( The workflow just hangs at the HttpSend activity. You can see the response I get back when the web service is tested in IE in my original question. Is this even a JSON response? And is the column from the response called "string" (based on the XML shown in my question above)?

Comment: in your example you have put `d/Title` in the `Path` field. But what should I put? My web service code is above in my question.